# Lisp -- How to add several hexadecimal numbers without base conversion?

Tags: math, lisp, numbers, hex, addition

Ii would like to know how to add several hexadecimal numbers in lisp without first converting them to another base. How could this be done?

Comment: If you are "converting a hexadecimal number to an integer", it sounds like you are converting a string to an integer, not a number in base 16 to a number in base 10. If you are actually converting to base 10, you're doing something wrong; if you're converting a string representing a hexadecimal number to an integer, then you're doing as well as you can.

Comment: There is no way to do hexadecimal math in lisp without base conversion?

Comment: "Base conversion" means, e.g., converting a string representing a number in base 16 to a string representing a number in base 10. I don't think that's what you're talking about here.

Comment: To elaborate a little more: Lisp doesn't store integers "in base 10" or something, they're just binary. Converting a hexadecimal string to an internally-represented integer is no more work than converting a decimal string to an internally-represented integer.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you show us some of your code?

Comment: If you want you can write functions that take hexadecimal strings and figure out the hexadecimal sum.  I guarantee you that this is less efficient than converting to integers and adding them.

Comment: @farm: It is not clear what you want to do, don't attack people that are asking you to elaborate. Numbers are always base 2 internally, other bases are dealt with by converting them from and to strings.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is 3 + A = D

Comment: Why can't you convert them to integers (if they're currently strings), add them, and display the result in hexadecimal?

Comment: because it wouldnt be as fun.

Comment: Since you seem so intent on doing this the 'fun' (heh) way, the obvious first question is: how are you storing these 'unconverted hexadecimal numbers'?  Strings?  Vectors of symbols?  Lists?  I've never heard of someone storing numbers in Lisp but not using the built-in types, so tell us how you're doing that.  Then we can come up with a function to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In GNU Emacs, hexadecimal numbers are tagged with #x.

```
(+ #x3 #xA)
13
```

I don't know offhand what Common LISP or Scheme use.

If what you have is something like

```
125A BD22 34FF
```

and you want to add them up, you'll have to take an edit pass over them to prepend the #x tags before you wrap them in (+ ...).

```
(+ #x125A #xBD22 #x34FF)
```

Comment: I just checked, and `#x` works in Clisp as well.

Answer (score 6):

Common Lisp:

```
> (setf *print-base* 16)

> (setf *read-base* 16)

> (+ a d)
17
```

Answer (score 3):

Hexadecimal is just a character representation of numbers using digits from 0 to F. **The Lisp implementation will typically convert hex numbers into its internal binary representation before addition**. You can then print the sum in hex if that's the desired presentation format:

```
(format T "~x" (+ #xA #x2))
```

You could write a function that implements the logic for symbolic addition of hexadecimal character digits, like that #\A plus #\2 is #\C, handling carry if you want to go beyond single hex digits. But such a function serves little purpose but as an exercise to demonstrate the algorithm for symbolic hexadecimal addition.